# Mysql SELECT query calculates hours left from two dates

Tags: mysql

I have a select query. I pass today `date(now())` and to date, I want my query to return no of hours there for that day.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), to) as timeleft
```

For eg: now() will be today date 16/10/2012 and to date will be 18/10/2012, I want my query to return 24 hours.

Is it possible to calculate exact hours from date, since it is almost half day over on 16/10/2012, can we get our output as 36 hours.

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to use [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) instead of [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

Comment: Just be careful with your data: TIMEDIFF will clip any result that exceeds 839 hours (~34 days). If you might need results larger than that, the UNIX_TIMESTAMP answer below is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to calculate the difference between 2 dates I use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to give me unix time and then calculate the seconds difference between the 2 dates.

```
SELECT ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(todate) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fromdate))/3600) AS hoursdiff
```

Comment: :For fromdate,can i get the no of hours from now to todate ?

Comment: if you run `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` with no parameters it will assume `NOW()` so `SELECT ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fromdate))/3600) as hoursdiff` will give you number of hours between "fromdate" and now

Answer (score 0):

You can Use :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(Hour,now(),'2012-10-18');
```